# Sorting Woo Commerce Product by sku for a specific category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to sort products for a specific category in WooCommerce by sky. Tried different combinations but non of work. Like I tried the bellow

```
      $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'sku',
            'order' => 'asc',
            'posts_per_page' => $atts['per_page'],
            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',

                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'terms' => array_map('sanitize_title', explode(',', $atts['category'])),
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'operator' => $atts['operator']
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                    'terms' => array_map('sanitize_title', explode(',', $atts['tags'])),
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'operator' => $atts['operator']
                )
            )
        ); 



$products = new WP_Query($args);
```

Where $attrs[] data are coming from shortcode parameters. But it does not sort product by sku ?

A help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a typo in the question description. It will be sku instead of sky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product sku (_sku) is saved as meta value, thus you cant simply say "order by sku", you should order by meta value, and set the meta keyto _sku. If they do not have a sku set the products will not be displayed.

Example:

```
args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'meta_key'   => '_sku',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_sku',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);
```

If your sku is numeric you should use "meta_value_num" if the sku's are strings then use "meta_value" instead.

You can read more about it here -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Awesome. Worked like a charm. Thanks mate. Really appreciate it.